# Selection Sort function for words

Tags: python, selection-sort

```
nums = [10, 70, 30, 100, 40, 45, 90, 80, 85]
words = ["dog","at", "good", "eye", "cat", "ball", "fish"]
 
def selectionSort(anArray):
    length = range(0, len(anArray)-1)
 
    for i in length:
        minValue = i
        for x in range(i+1, len(anArray)):
            if anArray[x] < anArray[minValue]:
                minValue = x
            if minValue != i:
                anArray[minValue], anArray[i] = anArray[i], anArray[minValue]
    return anArray
   
selectionSort(nums)
selectionSort(words)
print(nums)
print(words)
```

I am just learning about sort functions for my project I'm currently working on and I encountered an issue with sorting words with my current function somehow. The array with the numbers work but for some reason the words don't sort. I did a similar code for bubble sort and it was working but this one doesn't work.

Comment: Um... your numbers result is `[10, 30, 40, 70, 85, 45, 80, 90, 100]`...

Comment: You don't want to swap until after you've found the min...after the inner loop. So move `if minValue != i: anArray[minValue], anArray[i] = anArray[i], anArray[minValue]` to the outer loop.